# Compare 2 excel sheets based on 1 column

Tags: excel, compare

If I have 2 sheets in Excel that look like this:

**Sheet 1:**

```
|    IBM    |    First Name    |    Last Name    |
--------------------------------------------------
     1542          John                 Doe
     1487          Blah                 Blah
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
|    IBM    |    First Name    |    Last Name    |
--------------------------------------------------
     1542          John                 Doe
     1487          Blah                 Blah
     1849          Third                Name
```

Now, I need the outcome to provide me the people that exist in sheet 2 but do not exist in sheet 1, based on IBM.

So in this particular example, I need the outcome to be:

`IBM: 1849`

Can this be done in excel?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes it can in many different ways, array formulas, vba,...

Comment: @ScottCraner okay, can you show me how?

Comment: You need to be more specific on what method you are looking for, where the output would be,...

Comment: I would use the `COUNTIF function`

Comment: @ScottCraner I apologize, I don't know much about excel.. can the output be in the 3rd sheet?  I have used vba before so I can use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **COUNTIF function** is an easy way to check if a value exists in a data set:

> =COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1)

[image]

Comment: Which sheet do i put this formula on?  the first sheet is named `Sheet1` and the second sheet is named `PersonInfo`.. `IBM` on `Sheet1` is column1.. but column2 in `PersonInfo`

Comment: If you want to know which value is not existent in `Sheet1`, you would use `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,B1)` in sheet `PersonInfo` and if you want to know which value is not existent in `PersonInfo`, you would use `=COUNTIF(PersonInfo!B:B,A1)` in `Sheet1`.

Comment: if IBM is column 2 is on sheet PersonInfo then change the formula to  `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,B1)` this formula would go in the first row and then you need to autofill down to the end of your data.